# Developing windows 8.1 universal javascript phone apps with vs express

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I just read the article stating that with the 8.1 update windows phone apps will support winJS and I'm wondering if it's possible to develop them now with only an express edition of visual studio

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can install the 2013 Windows Express sku and get the latest updates. This will bring down the phone tools.